# Objectify One-to-Many and Many-To-One in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, relationship, objectify, many-to-one

I'm creating simple backend on Google App Engine using Objectify, that can store Users and thier Recipes.
Model look like this:
User has many Recipes, every Recipe has one author.

I want to be able to:

1. Get list of Recipes with authors in it
2. Get list of Users without fetching all recipes
3. Get one User with all his recipes

According to guide I have done this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private Long id;

@Index
private String name;

List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();

/* Other fields */

}
```

and Recipe :

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

@Id
Long id;

String name;

@Index
@Load
Ref<User> author;

/* Other fields */

}
```

I save Recipe with author (User object) in it.

1. and 2. requirements work fine,
   but when I try to get User with all recipes like this:

   ```
   public User get(@Named("id") long id) throws NotFoundException {

   User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();

   if (user == null) {
       throw new NotFoundException("Could not find User with ID: " + id);
   } else {
       List<Recipe> recipes = ofy().load().type(Recipe.class).filter("author", user).list();
       account.recipes = recipes;
   }
   return account;
   }
   ```

I get empty recipe list.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `author` property in your `Recipe` is a `Ref`, which is essentially a `Key`, so you need to filter on that key, like this:

```
List<Recipe> recipes = ofy().load().type(Recipe.class).filter("author =", Key.create(user)).list();
```

Incidentally, instead of using `.now()`, checking for `null`, then throwing an exception, you could use `.safe()` which does the same thing for you.